# Parse URL w/ django & nginx

Tags: python, django, url, nginx, encoding

So I'm building a django web application and trying to deploy it with nginx.

The langing page loads, but when I click on links, I get nginx 400 Bad Request errors.

The url in the browser will look like:

```
"GET /%7B$%%20url%20'members:member_login'%20%%7D HTTP/1.1" 400 173 "-" "-" "-"
```

However, if I go into the browser and manually delete the extra characters to get:

```
/url'members:member_login'
```

Then it works and renders the page just fine. Does anyone know what I can put in my nginx config file or in the django code to address this issue? It's been stumping me for literally 2 weeks.

Comment: This is a rather strange URL, it looks like you "encode"  a string in an URL. Usually the idea of Django is to write clean URLs that usually contain no characters that need to be escaped at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an error in your template: `%7b` is `{`, `%20` is . I think you might have a typo in the `href` attribute of the link you clicked, could it be:

```
<a href="{$% url 'members:member_login' %}">...
```

instead of

```
<a href="{% url 'members:member_login' %}">...
```

With these kinds of errors, always make sure to inspect the actual html source in your browser (right click -> 'View page source' in chrome).

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. It was exactly as you said. I accidentally had the dollar sign in there as a typo. Hopefully as I get more experience I can troubleshoot like that, I would've never realized that those characters represented other strings.